# How to filter items from an array of day values where a day's integer value has to match any timestamp from a second array of event items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, filter, timestamp

In JSX I am mapping through a number of days that I have calculated in a month:

```
  {range(daysInMonth).map((i) => (
          <div
            className="day-cell day-cell--in-month"
            key={i}
          >
            {i + 1}
          </div>
        ))}
```

I then have a array of events coming from an api:

```
const events = [
{
date: timestamp,
description: "Meeting with friends"
}
//More events//
]
```

How can I map through the array of events and match the event timestamp to the current timestamp of the date for the daysInMonth that is being mapped and then display the event description?

Comment: The OP wants to render the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)ed `dayInMonth` array items.

Comment: @PeterSeliger please can you expand on that?

Comment: _"to the current timestamp of the date"_ which date?

Comment: @ruleboy21 sorry for the confusion, for the date of the day in the month that is being mapped through.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I'm confused by how you would filter by another array?

Comment: Firstly, the OP has to assure that every item of `daysInMonth` features a timestamp/date too in order to be comparable to any item of the `events` array. Secondly, right before the mapping task the filtering has to take place. The filter function implements the comparison of the currently processed day item to any of the `events`' items. What does the structure of a `daysInMonth` item look like?

Comment: Kindly provide sample of the two arrays.

Comment: @ruleboy21 the daysInMonth is just a number, for example for Feb it would be 28.

Comment: _**" the daysInMonth is just a number, for example for Feb it would be 28."**_ ... thus, one can assume the timestamp/date value of an `events` item is an integer as well?

Comment: @PeterSeliger it's a timestamp from a MySQL database.

Comment: In that case, it will be impossible to achieve what you want since both arrays have nothing in common.

Comment: @PeterSeliger **"Firstly, the OP has to assure that every item of daysInMonth features a timestamp/date too in order to be comparable to any item of the events array."**  how can I achieve this?

Comment: @adherb ... _**"it's a timestamp from a MySQL database"**_ ... then within the already provided filter code of my answer one has to [get the `day`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) from each `events` item's `date` value in order to make it comparable to the integer value of each `daysInMonth` item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the above comment's assumption ...

> ***"the daysInMonth is just a number, for example for Feb it would be 28."** ... thus, one can assume the timestamp/date value of an events item is an integer as well?*

... applies, one could implement the preceding [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) task in collaboration with [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```
const events = [{
  date: timestamp,
  description: "Meeting with friends"
}/*, { More events }*/];


{
  range(
    
    daysInMonth
    
  ).filter(dayValue =>
    
    events.some(({ date }) => date === dayValue)
    
  ).map(dayValue => (
    <div
      className="day-cell day-cell--in-month"
      key={dayValue}
    >
      {dayValue + 1}
    </div>
  ))
}
```

***Edit***

> *"... thus, one can assume the timestamp/date value of an `events` item is an integer as well?" – Peter Seliger*
>
> > *"... it's a timestamp from a MySQL database." – adherb*
> >
> > > *"... then within the already provided filter code of my answer one has to [get the `day`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) from each `events` item's `date` value in order to make it comparable to the integer value of each `daysInMonth` item." – Peter Seliger*

```
const events = [{
  date: timestamp,
  description: "Meeting with friends"
}/*, { More events }*/];


{
  range(

    daysInMonth

  ).filter(dayValue =>
    events.some(({ date }) =>
      new Date(date).getDay() === dayValue
    )
  ).map(dayValue => (
    <div
      className="day-cell day-cell--in-month"
      key={dayValue}
    >
      {dayValue + 1}
    </div>
  ))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will give this a try and get back to you shortly!

Comment: What is the dayValue?

Comment: @adherb ... _**"What is the `dayValue`?"**_ ... the OP will figure this out alone. It's still the OP's original code with just an additional/preceding filter task.

Comment: Ok cool, thank you. So it doesn't matter that there is no timestamp for the daysInMonth to compare the events.date to?

Comment: @adherb ... 1/2 ... _**"So it doesn't matter that there is no timestamp for the daysInMonth to compare the events.date to?"**_ ... how could anyone know, except the OP. The OP alone knows the type of a `timestamp` values which was assigned to an `events` item's `date` property. The sophisticated guess is, that since a `daysInMonth` item is an ordinary integer value (the OP said so), the event item's `date` value is an integer as well. Otherwise on could not implement a meaningful filter.

Comment: @adherb ... 2/2 ... Thus as mentioned already before, in case there are no comparable time related values, the OP needs to make sure that such values are part of the data the OP is working with at render time.

Comment: @adherb ... are there any questions left? It can be that the OP might have too use [`getDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) instead of [`getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) but then I would ask why the OP doe not render the dates directly from the `events` array.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much Peter, really appreciate your help!

Comment: @adherb ... you're welcome. And out of curiosity, what else could possibly have been provided in order to not end up with just a zero score accepted answer?